# tensorflow compiled with cuda 9.1

Tags: tensorflow, compiler-errors, compilation

I'm beginer on tensorflow and i want to install the gpu version with cuda 9.0. The problem is that my gpu (Nvidia mx150) doesn't work with cuda 9.0 (only with cuda 9.1)... So i tried to compile my own version of tensorflow with cuda 9.1. But I'm still blocked cause during the compilation the compiler find an error so it doesn't compile... I don't know why but it's very frustrating. So if you have an already compiled version of tensorflow with cuda 9.1 I'm very intrested !

thanks in advance !

Comment: you should show the error at least

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have to use tensorflow 1.7, [this repository](https://github.com/mind/wheels) might have what you want. Just to be clear, I never tried any of them myself.

If you need to install on Windows, [this repository](https://github.com/fo40225/tensorflow-windows-wheel) might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks ! That is exactly what I'm looking for ! But I'm on windows and this depo only provide .whl for linux...

Comment: @PierreCarceller Please check if the new repository will help solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks ! It works ! :) I'm very curious to know how you found these git repos because before asking I've looked for by myself and I've never found them.

Comment: @PierreCarceller No magic. I'm just lucky and googled "tensorflow windows wheel".

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem a few weeks ago.

The problem is that the current version of TensorFlow (1.7) does not support CUDA9.1, please check this issue [comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/15656#issuecomment-362104182) and the discussion below.

Here are some options that I found:

1. Compile TensorFlow from the source code by your own
2. Find an existing whl file. ex. I fixed the issue by using a whl from the [repo](https://github.com/mind/wheels) (same as Y. Luo's answer)
3. Downgrade to CUDA 9.0
4. Wait until Tensorflow supports CUDA9.1 :)